# Create labels and textboxes in a form dynamically where the text in the label should come from my sql compact database

Tags: vb.net

I want to create `Labels` and `TextBoxes` in a `Form` dynamically.
The text in the `Label` should come from my `SQL Compact` DataBase.

When I run the `Form`, it gives me this error:

> Conversion from string "" to type 'double' is not valid.

I've tried researching but I can't find an answer.
Thanks

Here is my code:

```
Public Function countrows()
    checkServer()

    CnString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dbEsyPOS.sdf;Persist Security Info=True; Password=CQ25dbEsyPOS"
    Dim sqlCon As New SqlCeConnection(CnString)
      sqlCon.Open()
    Using cmd As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT *FROM tbl_sale ")
        Using sda As New SqlCeDataAdapter
            cmd.Connection = sqlCon
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd

            Using sqlDT As New DataTable

                Try
                    sda.Fill(sqlDT)
                    If (sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                        For i As Integer = 0 To sqlDT.Rows.Count - 1
                            Dim lblTitle As Label = New Label()

                            lblTitle.Name = "Label" & i.ToString()
                            lblTitle.Text = CStr(sqlDT.Rows(i)(0)("term_of_payment"))
                            Panel2.Controls.Add(lblTitle)
                        Next
                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Oops :" + ex.Message)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Ps I'm a newbie and any help or correction would be appreciated :)

Comment: What are you trying to do at this line:   lblTitle.Text = CnString(sqlDT.Rows(i)(0)("term_of_payment"))?

Comment: Also your connection string is not set until after you create the connection?

Comment: I wanted the text in the label to come from a value in a column of the database. term_of_payment is the name of the column

Comment: I'll change that, thanks

Comment: How does this make sense: `If sqlDT.Rows.Count = ""`?  How can a property of type `Integer` ever equal an empty `String`?  Turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties immediately and then fix all the typing issues that it flags.  You'll be starting from a better point.  Also, turn it `On` in the IDE options so that it will be `On` by default in future projects.

Comment: Also, that comparison is inside an `If` block where you have already determined that `sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0` is `True`, so I don't even know what you're actually trying to achieve there.

Comment: I forgot to remove that code as it isn't useful here, I've edited it out now.

Comment: For future reference, ALWAYS tell us which line a compilation error or exception occurs on.  We should not have to guess anything that you already know.

Comment: With regards to your controls, I strongly recommend that you add a `TableLayoutPanel` to your form with two columns.  You can then simply add controls to it and they will be positioned automatically.  You can also access them easily later by column and row index.  That said, I can't help wondering whether a `DataGridView` with the first column read-only would be a better option.  You could then simply bind your `DataTable` and simplify things considerably.

Comment: Also, if you're not going use the `DataTable` afterwards then you shouldn't use one at all.  If you just want to read the data from it then use a data reader in the first place.

Comment: The error appears in form of a message box and doesn't specify what line the error is in, after that the form appears but no label is produced

Comment: The error appears in a message box because you're putting it there.  If you debugged your code properly then you'd see exactly which line was executed before it jumped to the `Catch` clause, or you could look at the stack trace of the exception, or you could just not catch it and let it crash, in which case the IDE would highlight the line in question.  This is a perfect example of why you should not catch `Exception`. It's reasonable that you get a database failure there but this is just bad code so you shouldn't be catching that exception.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code doesn't make sense:

```
lblTitle.Text = CnString(sqlDT.Rows(i)(0)("term_of_payment"))
```

I'm guessing that what you're actually trying to do is get a `String` from the 'term_of_payment' column.  That would look like this:

```
lblTitle.Text = CStr(sqlDT.Rows(i)("term_of_payment"))
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do, thanks for the correction.